# Can I concatenate each values of arrays without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

just a simple question. I have two arrays `{"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"}` and `{1;2;3;4;5}` and want to concatenate each of them like `{"A1";"B2";"C3";"D4";"E5"}`. Is this kind of manipulation possible without VBA but maybe with CSE formula?

Answer (score 3):

Seems I was stucked, I found answer just after tea break... sorry for bothering!

As CSE Formula: `=CONCAT({"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"} & {1;2;3;4;5})`

Comment: I you want to do something with the remaining array you wouldn't even need to use concat. Just `={"A";"B";"C";"D";"E"}&{1;2;3;4;5}` does the trick. By the way, no need to appologize.